# Is the greeting, "How do?", a valid sentence and has it ever been used?

Tags: greetings

I've heard people say that greetings from before, and I picked it up from them. I was wondering if it is a legal sentence and its  origin.

Comment: I think you are referring to "Howdy?" which is a contraction of the actual greeting - "How do you do?"

Comment: No, I believe "how do" is also an expression. Both derive from "how do you do".

Comment: Question title: "Has it ever been used?". Question body: "I've heard people say it before". That's half your question answered then: Yes it has been used. In your own presence.

Comment: It's a slightly affected (less "clipped") dialectal variant on the old US standard [Howdie!](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/howdie). But I think OP's version was/is more *British* (I can't imagine anyone saying it with an aspirated /h/ before ***'ow do?***).

Comment: "How do?" is a widely used Yorkshire greeting - but do greetings have to be grammatical.

Comment: Hi Anonymous - you should ask this on the "ELL" site.  Note that there's no such thing, really, as a "legal" sentence in English .. but you can learn about these issues on ELL.

Comment: FWIW @Chenmunka i've heard "How do" used everywhere; I did not know it was particularly regional BrE.  It strikes me as archaic - Colonel Potter from "MASH" would probably say "How do?" in greeting.

Comment: If you're equating 'a valid sentence' with 'acceptable', note that (1) there is no single agreed definition of 'sentence' and (2) what some call 'sentence fragments' and/or 'sentence substitutes' (How do? / Hello / On the table ...) are usually considered quite acceptable in all but the most formal registers.

Comment: I can confirm that it was widely used when I was growing up in East Yorkshire in the 1950s and 1960s.  But it now sounds very old-fashioned as well as regional.  Even in the 60s, young people were saying 'Hiya'.

Comment: How do, folks? I grew up hearing that expression occasionally in Texas as an alternative to "Howdy" and "Howdy do" (not to mention "Hello" and "Hi").  I was surprised to learn just now that it has (or had) a separate existence in northern England.

Comment: My work colleague greets me with "How do?" every morning.  He's from the north of England.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not one hears ***how do*** commonly may be a matter of locale.  English is pronounced, mispronounced, and generally mauled differently in each corner of the world where it is spoken.

I have heard the greeting **how do?** at least three times since yesterday noon in rural NE US.

It is, as others have said, a shortening of "**How do you do.**"

Although one can parse the parent phrase into a grammatically complete (if slightly ridiculous) sentence, in which the subject *you* performs the intensified verb *do do* which is modified by the adverb *how*, the exercise in doing so would be purely academic *doodoo*, as in all probability few if any greeters have truly wished to know **how**, in fact, someone else **does do, did do or has done doing** since the 18th century.

Instead, the phrase falls into the category of ***phatic expressions***. All hail Wikipedia:

> In linguistics, a **phatic expression** is one whose only function is to perform a social task, as opposed to conveying information.
>   The term "phatic communion" was coined by anthropologist Bronislaw Malinowski in his essay "The Problem of Meaning in Primitive Languages," which appeared in 1923 in The Meaning of Meaning by C.K. Ogden and I.A. Richards. The term comes from the Greek "phatos" (spoken, that may be spoken), and from "phanai" (to speak, say).

Like other ***phatic expressions*** (e.g. *Hi,* *Hey,* *Yo,* and *Heighdy-Ho*) it neither needs nor wants grammatical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old Saturday Western form of greeting, something you might have heard while watching a Roy Rogers western, or perhaps a wannabe *Gone With the Wind* Southern picture.  I'm sure I've heard it a few dozen times in old movies.

Basically it's a very informal version of "How do you do?" (Imagine the cowboy tipping his dusty hat to the lady as he says it.)

I suppose it may still be in use (if it ever was) in the Western US, but it's not a common idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Heard people say "How Do" many times in the past in the Midwest. Just heard an older lady say it in the store the other day here in California. It just means Hello!

Answer (score 1):

My grandmother from Pella, Iowa, used this as a jocular greeting.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't *really* a proper sentence or greeting, but someone could have interpreted "Howdy?" as "How do?" or they might have even just created slang for "How do you do?"  Personally, I've never heard anyone use it, although I have seen it once in an old book.